# Read a filename while running and insert it (bash)

Tags: bash, svg, dot

I'm new to bash so I need a lot of help for probably a little thing. I'll try to explain, what I want to do or where I need help. (Excuse my english if I make mistakes)

There is a Script, which creates a numbers of `.gv` Files. In those `.gv` Files are some commands to make a graph. With "dot" I'm gonna create a picture with that.

My code now is

```
dot -Tsvg *.gv -o ????.svg
```

I need help with those `????` - In the `*.gv` are all `.gv` listed (you know what I mean I guess...) anyway, the `????`'s should have the same name as the file,but there are more than one file so I don't know how to code that. It just should take the Filename while it's running.

Answer (score 1):

The `-O` option generates names for you, based on the input name and the output format.